# Rails 2.3.11 + Passenger 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm facing a problem to run a rails 2.3.11 app with Passenger 5.0. First I was receving 403 - Forbidden Error, no matter what I did in my vhost config. Searching the web I realize that was necessary to use a config.ru file to passenger start my application. But now I get the error: "Incomplete response received from application". So, searching I found that this error could be avoid setting the secret key at secrets.yml. So I ran rake secret and created the file secret.yml in config/ folder, but I'm still receiving the same error: "Incomplete response received from application".

It's possible to run Rails 2.3.11 with Passenger 5 or do I have to downgrade it?

Hope someone could help.

Comment: No need to downgrade according to https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/03/04/phusion-passenger-5-0-1-released/

Comment: Thanks, was helpfull!

Comment: https://railslts.com/

Comment: After some ajustments now I get the Passenger error page, with the mensage:
no such file to load -- rack (LoadError)

Comment: [SOLVED] I had to restart my server to get it working again.